# How to join a hive table with a pandas dataframe in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a hive table `db.hive_table` and a pandas dataframe `df`. I wish to use `pyspark.SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate().sql` to join them. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Convert both to pyspark dataframe and then join dfs.

```
# Pandas to Spark
df_sp = spark_session.createDataFrame(df_pd)
```

```
# Convert hive table to df - sqlContext is of type HiveContext
df_hive = sqlContext.table(tablename)
```

Join the two dfs.

```
joined_df = df_sp.join(df_hive, df_sp.id == df_hive.id).select('df_sp.*', 'df_hive.*')
```